# MySQL same max value, different instances

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
id | day | count
----------------
 u   tue   1
 u   wed   4
 w   wed   5
 x   mon   5
 y   mon   5
 x   tue   2
```

I want to return the rows with the highest count on each day.
So I want to get this table:

```
id | day | count
----------------
 w   wed   5
 x   mon   5
 y   mon   5
 x   tue   2
```

Here's my sql, but it's not giving me the right output:

```
select id, day, MAX(count)
from Table
group by day
```

It is giving me:

```
id | day | count
----------------
 w   wed   5
 y   mon   5
 x   tue   2
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `u   wed   4` from desired output?

Comment: no, because I want the maximum based on the day not the id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a sub-query:

```
select * from table 
  join (select day,max(count) as count from table group by day) as max_rec
    on table.day = max_rec.day and table.count = max_rec.count
```

[sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5c4b/2)

Comment: Thanks, That works great. I will have to work out in my mind the logic of it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.* from
Table t1
JOIN
(
select day, max(count) count
from Table
group by day
)t2 ON t1.day=t2.day AND t1.count=t2.count
```